# Vue axios get http not returning the response data

Tags: api, vue.js, axios, vuex

I have data.js importing axios and VueAxios as below:

When I am calling the `getRecordTypes` function in `mutations(vuex)` returns undefined. But when I do console log it returns the correct data set.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

let BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000'
const API_URL = `${BASE_URL}/api/v1/`

export default {
  getRecordTypes () {
    let results = []
    let url = `${API_URL}record_types`
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data) // return the actual arrary of data
      results = response.data
      return results
    }).catch(error => { console.log(error) })
  }
}
```

In my vuex `mutations js` file, I have imported the above `data.js` file like below:

```
import data from '@/lib/api/data'

export default {
  setRecordTypes (state) {
    console.log(data.getRecordTypes())  // return undefined
    state.recordTypes = data.getRecordTypes()
  }
}
```

I am new to Vue js and not sure what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getRecordTypes()` did't return anything, also is async function, actually return a `Promise` object.

All methods of `axios` return `Promise` object, rather than a direct result of response. If you understand the basics of `async` and `Promise` first, this will make learning easier :)

```
// data.js
export default {
  getRecordTypes () {
    let url = `${API_URL}record_types`
    // add return
    return axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data) // return the actual arrary of data
      results = response.data
      return results
    }).catch(error => { console.log(error) })
  }
}

// mutations.js
import data from '@/lib/api/data'

export default {
  setRecordTypes (state) {
    // async
    data.getRecordTypes().then(results => {
      state.recordTypes = results
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks and it's worked now and I didn't know much about these vuex concept. Thanks for you to ask me to look more into details.

Answer (score 0):

Your result variable is defined with the 'let' keyword.
That's means he is only available on the getRecordTypes scope level, so you can't re-assigned him in your axios promise.

You need to assign result in the resolve promise like this:

```
axios.get(url)
.then(response => {
  let result = [];
  result = response.data;
  console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, but I got the same results. The console log return a data but not when I call the method which is not return anything. I have updated my question for your information.

Comment: Mmh i guess the problem is into your mutation.
Try to console.log(data); and tell me what it returns.
Maybe the result value is accesible using data.result but i'm not sure.